# Vega-Lite: More Complex Sort Functions

Tags: vega-lite, vega

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/sort.html

Is there a way to pass in a more complex sort to a vega lite chart? For example could I pass something like a javascript function in to work as a comparator?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's not possible to directly pass in a custom sort function directly.

However, you could calculate a custom field using the [calculate](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/calculate.html) transformation to create a new field with the [expression language](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) (which is a subset of Javascript) , then use that field to perform your sort.

If you have a custom javascript function that you'd like to call from inside the expression language, you can register it using the [Vega extension API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/extensibility/#expressionFunction), and then use it in your `calculate` transform.